# VBA code not accounting for the JPEG/PNG pictures in the document

Tags: vba, ms-word

My use case is as follows:
I want to have a macro to display the count of all the pictures in my document.

I have put together the following code. However, when i run it on a document that has a few JPEG/PNG images, the count returned is `0`.

What am I doing wrong here please:

```
Sub countfigures()
    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    Dim figureCount As Integer
    figureCount = 0
    
    Dim shape As shape
    For Each shape In doc.Shapes
        ' Check if the shape is a picture
        If shape.Type = msoPicture Then
            figureCount = figureCount + 1
        End If
    Next shape
    
    MsgBox "Number of figures in the document: " & figureCount
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely the 'Shape' is actually an 'InlineShape' ... try this:

```
Sub countfigures()
    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    Dim figureCount As Integer
    figureCount = 0
    
    Dim shape As shape
    For Each shape In doc.Shapes
        ' Check if the shape is a picture
        Debug.Print shape.Type
        If shape.Type = msoPicture Then
            figureCount = figureCount + 1
        End If
    Next shape
    
    Dim inlineShape As inlineShape
    For Each inlineShape In doc.InlineShapes
        ' Check if the InlineShape is a picture
        Debug.Print inlineShape.Type
        If inlineShape.Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then
            figureCount = figureCount + 1
        End If
    Next inlineShape
    
    MsgBox "Number of figures in the document: " & figureCount
End Sub
```

... I included two `Debug.Print` statements (which you can remove once your code is working just as you want it to) so you can see the type of the Shape / InlineShape ... there are many such types and they are different for each of Shape and InlineShape as you can see here [MsoShapeType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoshapetype) and here [WdInlineShapeType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdinlineshapetype)